# Getting started with datomic and clojure - Could not locate datomic/api__init.class on classpath

Tags: clojure, classpath, dependency-management, leiningen, datomic

I am trying to run datomic's in-memory database with this tutorial https://clojureverse.org/t/a-quick-way-to-start-experimenting-with-datomic/5004 with the free version. I downloaded the .zip file and put it in program files. Then I created a project with leiningen and I did the other steps indicated in the tutorial, but when I want to evaluate the lines with the repl for creating the database and connection it throws:

"Error:
Syntax error compiling at (c:\Users\usuario\Desktop\clojure\datomic-shortcut\src\datomic_shortcut\core.clj:7:3).
No such namespace: d"

... and when I evaluate the entire file, the following:

Evaluating file: core.clj
Syntax error (FileNotFoundException) compiling at (c:\Users\usuario\Desktop\clojure\datomic-shortcut\src\datomic_shortcut\core.clj:1:1).
Could not locate datomic/api__init.class, datomic/api.clj or datomic/api.cljc on classpath.
Evaluation of file core.clj failed: class clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException

When checking the .m2 folder there is no datomic's dependency, even after trying 'lein deps'

I think it can be solved with lein pom/jar/install sequence but I dont find where or I dont know how to download the .jar file.

Any help or information is welcome.. thanks!

-------------EDIT--------------------

Im sorry, the .m2 folder contains the ...m2\repository\com\datomic\datomic-free\0.9.5697\datomic-free-0.9.5697.jar file indeed.
No errors with 'lein deps'

My project.clj:

```
(defproject datomic-shortcut "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "EPL-2.0 OR GPL-2.0-or-later WITH Classpath-exception-2.0"
            :url "https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0/"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.1"]
                 [com.datomic/datomic-free "0.9.5697"]]
  :source-paths ["src"]
  :repl-options {:init-ns datomic-shortcut.core})
```

My core.clj:

```
(ns datomic-shortcut.core
  (:require [datomic.api :as d]))

(def db-uri "datomic:mem://foo")

(comment
  (d/create-database db-uri)
  (def conn (d/connect db-uri)))
```

I realized the classpath hasn't the .jar file in it.

```
C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\clojure\datomic-shortcut>lein classpath
=>
C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\clojure\datomic-shortcut\test;
C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\clojure\datomic-shortcut\src;
C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\clojure\datomic-shortcut\dev-resources;
C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\clojure\datomic-shortcut\resources;
C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\clojure\datomic-shortcut\target\classes;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\com\datomic\datomic-lucene-core\3.3.0\datomic-lucene-core-3.3.0.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\18.0\guava-18.0.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\com\h2database\h2\1.3.171\h2-1.3.171.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\apache\activemq\artemis-commons\1.4.0\artemis-commons-1.4.0.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\nrepl\nrepl\0.6.0\nrepl-0.6.0.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-juli\7.0.27\tomcat-juli-7.0.27.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\clojure-complete\clojure-complete\0.2.5\clojure-complete-0.2.5.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.7\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.7.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\leinjacker\leinjacker\0.4.1\leinjacker-0.4.1.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.0.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.7\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\clojure\core.contracts\0.0.1\core.contracts-0.0.1.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\janino\commons-compiler\2.6.1\commons-compiler-2.6.1.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\com\datomic\datomic-free\0.9.5697\datomic-free-0.9.5697.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\clojure\core.unify\0.5.3\core.unify-0.5.3.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\apache\johnzon\johnzon-core\0.9.4\johnzon-core-0.9.4.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.9.2\commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\log4j-over-slf4j\1.7.7\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\useful\useful\0.8.5-alpha2\useful-0.8.5-alpha2.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-nop\1.7.7\slf4j-nop-1.7.7.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\clojure\tools.cli\0.3.5\tools.cli-0.3.5.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\lein-datomic\lein-datomic\0.2.0\lein-datomic-0.2.0.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\fressian\fressian\0.6.5\fressian-0.6.5.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-json_1.0_spec\1.0-alpha-1\geronimo-json_1.0_spec-1.0-alpha-1.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\me\raynes\conch\0.4.0\conch-0.4.0.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\apache\activemq\artemis-core-client\1.4.0\artemis-core-client-1.4.0.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.7\slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\clojure\clojure\1.10.1\clojure-1.10.1.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-all\4.0.39.Final\netty-all-4.0.39.Final.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\clojure\core.specs.alpha\0.2.44\core.specs.alpha-0.2.44.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\janino\commons-compiler-jdk\2.6.1\commons-compiler-jdk-2.6.1.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\clojure\tools.macro\0.1.1\tools.macro-0.1.1.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-jdbc\7.0.27\tomcat-jdbc-7.0.27.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar;
C:\Users\usuario\.m2\repository\org\clojure\spec.alpha\0.2.176\spec.alpha-0.2.176.jar
```

So then I tried:

```
C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\clojure\datomic-shortcut>java -cp C:/Users/usuario/.m2/repository/com/datomic/datomic-free/0.9.5697/datomic-free-0.9.5697.jar clojure.main
Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal clojure.main
```

Comment: Can you update the question to include your `project.clj` file? Are there any errors when running `lein deps`? The version seems to be correct [according to Clojars](https://clojars.org/com.datomic/datomic-free), so I'm thinking maybe it's a problem in the project file

Comment: Thanks for answering @DenisFuenzalida, here is a little more information.

Comment: Your `java cp C:...` command won't work because you need many more Jar files in the classpath, that's why you'll want lein to help with that. I checked the post in Clojureverse and it works for me, the only thing I did differently was creating the project with `lein new app datomic-shortcut` (note the "new app", not just "new"). Can you start a Clojure repl with `lein repl` in your project? What version of Java does it show with `java -version`? Here's a gist with the version I tested: https://gist.github.com/dfuenzalida/4aa6ce9ef27074b8603108fc1594a45a

Comment: I asked a friend for help and tried 'lein repl'. It turns out that the project did not have enough memory available, so it threw an error like this:

IllegalArgumentExceptionInfo: db.error / not-enough-memory (datomic.objectCacheMax + datomic.memoryIndexMax) exceeds 75% of JVM RAM datomic.error / arg.

Fixed it with :jvm-opts ["-Xmx1024m"]. So I guess it was the same way that you suggested ... thank you very much for your time! I am new to the community ... should I write this as an answer to my question?

Comment: I don't think it's needed, I'm glad it finally worked for you.